# Alertmanager error: caller=notifier msg="Error sending alert" err="bad response status 500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Prometheus is logging errors with what appears to be calls to an API url that is wrong:

```
Feb 06 13:38:54 ip-192-168-0-xxx.ec2.internal prometheus[27909]: level=error ts=2019-02-06T13:38:54.946934196Z caller=notifier.go:473 component=notifier alertmanager=http://192.168.22.105:4194/api/v1/alerts count=0 msg="Error sending alert" err="bad response status 500 Internal Server Error"
Feb 06 13:38:54 ip-192-168-0-xxx.ec2.internal prometheus[27909]: level=error ts=2019-02-06T13:38:54.946955868Z caller=notifier.go:473 component=notifier alertmanager=http://192.168.22.73:4194/api/v1/alerts count=0 msg="Error sending alert" err="bad response status 500 Internal Server Error"
Feb 06 13:38:54 ip-192-168-0-xxx.ec2.internal prometheus[27909]: level=error ts=2019-02-06T13:38:54.946975398Z caller=notifier.go:473 component=notifier alertmanager=http://192.168.22.87:4194/api/v1/alerts count=0 msg="Error sending alert" err="bad response status 500 Internal Server Error"
```

The IP addresses in each of these errors are actually internal IPs of nodes that are being monitored. So somehow there is a bad configuration somewhere in prometheus that is causing this. Shouldn't IPs be the IP address of alertmanager?

Can anyone point to me where I might look to resolve this in my prometheus configuration?

Answer (score 0):

try calling the API yourself (ie: do the calls that prometheus is trying to make).
check the error logs of alertmanager.

alertmanager is returning `500 Internal Server Error` so something is wrong there.

If you open a web browser and try loading `http://192.168.22.105:4194/api/v1/alerts` (or if you do a `curl` or `wget` from a machine in your network that can reach those IPs), you should be getting a json response with list of alerts. or at least an empty response with `{"status":"success","data":[]}`

> The IP addresses in each of these errors are actually internal IPs of nodes that are being monitored.

That's wrong. Prometheus is trying to send the alerts to those IPs. So those alerts should correspond to AlertManager instances.

If AlertManager is not running in those IPs, that's why it's failing. Prometheus it's trying to call the Alertmanager's API (`/api/v1/alerts`).

To *monitor* those nodes, prometheus needs access to `{IP}/metrics` instead.